# Win32 exception no application is assigned to the specified file C#

Tags: c#, forms, file, win32exception

I have a problem with my Winforms Application. I have a database where the user can store files in. Doesnt matter if it is pdf, png etc...The user should see the file when double clicking on a row in a datagridview. I tried it like this:

```
private void DataGridCPU_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = sqlCon.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select Dok from cpuTabelle where Id='" + this.DataGridCPU.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'";
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                var data = (byte[])reader["Dok"];
                var newName = this.DataGridCPU.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString()+"_"+ this.DataGridCPU.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                File.WriteAllBytes(newName, data);
                System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                p.StartInfo.FileName = newName;
                p.Start();
                p.WaitForExit();
```

When I double click on a row now the exception in the title is thrown. 
I also tried to add `p.StartInfo.ErrorDialog=true;` before the `p.Start();` line but then the Errorbox opens which says *the file is not associated with an app for performing this action* and a following exception: *the operation was cancelled by the user.* 
I really dont know what to do... 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not your problem, but an important note: NEVER construct SQL Statements from user input - this make you wide open for SQL injection attacks; use parametrized statements instead.

Comment: To your probem: which values does `newName` have? Does it include the correct file extension?

Comment: @KlausGütter Ok i will try to change the SQL Statements. The Values of newName so Cell[0].Value is my Id Column and Cell[1].Value is my Name Column without a file extension.

Comment: If there is no file extension, Windows does not know how to open the file. If you did not store the file extension in the database, you might try to guess it by looking at the first few bytes; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Comment: Ok, i added an extra column for the extension and now it works fine. Thanks for your very fast answer to this topic. Much appreciated. Thanks!